# Calculate cumulative returns on Google Sheet with blank cells

Tags: google-sheets

[image]
The formula that is in the Cumulative Return cell that is showing -0.09% is this.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(J2), 1, (1+J2))*IF(ISBLANK(J3), 1, (1+J3))*IF(ISBLANK(J4), 1, (1+J4))-1
```

How can I make it so that this automatically performs what I want when I insert new rows into Return. Right now I am having to keep adding IF(ISBLANK(J#), 1, (1+J#)) into the formula manually with incrementing # number.

Comment: Sorry I don't think what I am trying to achieve is as simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=PRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(J2:J4),1+(J2:J4) ,1)))-1`

The range is the key to the effectiveness of this formula.

When entering a new return/row, be careful to ensure that the formula range expands to include the new row. Don't enter a new row *above* the first row in the range, or *below* the last row in the range.

**BEFORE**

### [image: Before]

**AFTER**
[image: After]

---